# Does anyone recognize this sequence? What is its grow rate as a function of j?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ s_1 = 1 $$
$$ s_j = (\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} s_i) + 1 $$

Comment: $s_j=j$ for all $j$.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing one should always do when faced with an unknown sequence is work out the first few terms.

$$
\begin{align}
s_1 & &&= 1 \\
s_2 &= (1) + 1 &&= 2 \\
s_3 &= (1 + 2) + 1 &&= 4 \\
s_4 &= (1 + 2 + 4) + 1 &&= 8 \\
\end{align}
$$

The pattern should be obvious now.